# How can I create a silent refresh action creator for custom redux middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I'm implementing a silent refresh for my application that basically replaces an existing expired access token with a new one from an httpOnly, secure, sameSite cookie. The flow looks like this:

[Silent refresh process diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1Wot.png)

After banging my head against the wall with axios interceptors, I decided that some custom redux middleware was better suited for my purposes. I've got everything working as expected (after much inception-esque trial and error), but it feels so clunky and inefficient. Here is my middleware file:

```
// Redux middleware
import users from "../api/auth/users";
import {
  USER_REFRESH_FAIL,
  USER_REFRESH_REQUEST,
  USER_REFRESH_SUCCESS,
} from "../constants/userConstants";

const requestMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => async (
  action
) => {
  const { userLogin } = getState();
  if (!userLogin.userInfo || typeof action !== "function") return next(action);
  const { accessTokenExpiry } = userLogin.userInfo;
  const accessTokenExpiryTime = new Date(accessTokenExpiry).getTime();

  if (Date.now() >= accessTokenExpiryTime) {
    if (userLogin.refreshing) {
      return next(action);
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_REFRESH_REQUEST,
      });

      await users
        .post(
          "/refresh",
          { existingAccessToken: userLogin.userInfo.accessToken },
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        )
        .then(({ data }) => {
          dispatch({
            type: USER_REFRESH_SUCCESS,
            payload: data,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          dispatch({
            type: USER_REFRESH_FAIL,
            payload:
              error.response && error.response.data.error.message
                ? error.response.data.error.message
                : error.message,
          });
        });

      return next(action);
    }
  } else {
    return next(action);
  }
};

export default requestMiddleware;
```

My backend "/refresh" route simply confirms the refresh credentials (from the cookie) and then replaces the expired access token with a new one and sends it back along with the expiry time. I really want to move this action to live with my other action creators so I can easily use it on other parts of my application. Specifically as an application-wide useEffect if a user's info is undefined but the cookie still exists (refreshing the page or closing the session). I've tried defining it in my user actions file like this:

```
// User action creators
export const refresh = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REFRESH_REQUEST,
    });

    const { userLogin } = getState();

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    const { data } = await users.post(
      "/refresh",
      { existingAccessToken: userLogin.userInfo.accessToken },
      config
    );

    await dispatch({
      type: USER_REFRESH_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REFRESH_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.error.message
          ? error.response.data.error.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

And then reformatting my middleware to something like this:

```
// Redux middleware
import {refresh} from "../actions/userActions";

const requestMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState }) => (next) => async (
  action
) => {
  const { userLogin } = getState();
  if (!userLogin.userInfo || typeof action !== "function") return next(action);
  const { accessTokenExpiry } = userLogin.userInfo;
  const accessTokenExpiryTime = new Date(accessTokenExpiry).getTime();

  if (Date.now() >= accessTokenExpiryTime) {
    if (userLogin.refreshing) {
      return next(action);
    } else {
      await dispatch(refresh())

      return next(action);
    }
  } else {
    return next(action);
  }
};

export default requestMiddleware;
```

But when I test it out I'm getting a maximum call stack size exceeded error. My gut is telling me that it definitely has to do with the way I'm dispatching the imported action in my middleware and I'm blundering the asynchronous flow. I feel like it's something simple but I'm going in circles chasing my own tail and can't figure it out. Any help with this would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!
Seth

Comment: How about using `setTimeout`

Comment: Where do you mean to use that specifically?

Comment: Try this, create a function for fetching `nextToken`. And whenever you're logging in call that `nextToken` function inside it with some timeout (calculated as per the token expiry time). Inside nextToken, at last call itself (`nextToken`) again with setTimeout.